# Jssor slider - some transitions are very slow

Tags: jquery, jssor

Please take a look at this live page which is still underdeveloped.

http://tt.fbcwinterretreat.org/index.php/videos/2015-03-06-03-44-24

Some of the transitions perform very slowly, especially transitions like "dodge Dance Outside in Random" or "Swing Outside in Stairs". 
Before I can improve the performace, I need to know the cause of this slowness. Is it related to my using the images as background-image? Or is it related to the cast_sender.js error we keep getting from the ytiframe? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the transition code of `Swing Outside in Stairs`, you can see `$Cols: 8, $Rows: 4`.

To run the transition, it will create `8 x 4 = 32` copies of slide content. And your slide contains video element (which is heavy to render).